# Apache POI docx: HTML as an altChunk with photo

Tags: apache-poi

Good morning
I need to add HTML text to my DOCX file using Apache POI. 
This HTML has a photo. The link to the photo points to a resource that is visible only in the internal lan. So when the .docx is generatated when I open the document outside the lan I can't see the image.
Is it possible to save the imagine in the "media" folder of .docx and create a reference to it in the "_rels" folder? 
If yes, where I can find the documentation that describe how to do it with Apache Poi? 
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Why the `altChunk`? Why not using the native `XWPF` methods (`XWPFRun.addPicture`) ? That manages the embedding of the picture into the `*.docx` file.

Comment: Hello. In my app I need to build a .docx form two sets of data: normal text and HTML text.  HTML text is provided from a javascript rich text editor. In this rich text editor there are some photos. The photos are saved as html tag "<img>" and the link to the photo in the internal lan. So I can't use  methods (XWPFRun.addPicture).

Comment: Then it is impossible since `altChunk` cannot link to the `media` inside the `*.docx` `ZIP` file system. The `HTML` of the `altChunk` could contain `<img src="data:image/...;base64 .../>` but to create the `base64` of the image you would need the binaries of the image. And then you also could use `XWPFRun.addPicture`.

Comment: I tried to insert the base64 of the image inside the <img> tag. The document is created but when I open it the image is missing. Thanks for your  support.

Comment: See [html-docx-js](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js) how to create MHTML with images for MS Word. Just note, it [does not work on Mac](https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js/issues/129).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to do it with Apache POI library